# How can I know whether I'm infected by StripedFly malware?

Tags: malware

I was reading [this](https://www.it-connect.fr/malware-stripedfly-1-million-pc-windows-linux-infectes/) article, and decided to search for `sd-pam` in the processes of one of my laptops.

I did `ps -x | grep -i "sd-pam"`, and got

```
2864 ?        S      0:00 (sd-pam)
29172 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto -i sd-pam
```

So I think I've got infected with this malware somehow. The laptop is old, and I remember during covid times my camera working without being user-activated (light was on), but I could never find out why.

The problem is that `user@.service` also creates a subprocess called sd-pam, as can be seen in its respective `man` page (if I read correctly).

How can I find out whether my old laptop is infected or not with

I'm not an expert, nor even an experienced user/cybersecurity guy.

PS: the article is in french. Here's also an [article in english](https://www.zetter-zeroday.com/p/sophisticated-stripedfly-spy-platform).
PS2: This question came about when I asked another [question on the Ubuntu.SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1490990/how-to-remove-stripedfly-malware-from-ubuntu-22-04) and two comments made me realize that the probability of a false positive was not negligible.